# Aggregate and DCast

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with the following content:

```
      betnr   persnr status year
1: 50536224 60961963 normal 1997
2: 50536224 62841998 normal 1997
3: 50536224 62841998 normal 1998
4: 50536224 60961963   fire 1998
5: 50536224 62841998   fire 1999
6: 50536224 60961963   hire 1996
7: 50536224 62841998   hire 1996
8: 50536224 63000343  SHORT 1998
```

And I would like to aggregate over `betnr`, `year` the number of different `status` happening. The following had been my approach:

```
aggregateNStatus <- test[, .N, by=list(betnr, year, status)]
dcast.data.table(aggregateNStatus, betnr + year  ~ status)
      betnr year SHORT fire hire normal
1: 50536224 1996    NA   NA    2     NA
2: 50536224 1997    NA   NA   NA      2
3: 50536224 1998     1    1   NA      1
4: 50536224 1999    NA    1   NA     NA
```

which is exactly what I want, but it seems cumbersome. Given the awesomeness of `data.table`, isn't there a way to do this in one step?

Comment: Like your last line very much. Encouraging. The next-to-next version (1.9.8) will have more functionalities to `dcast` :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `aggregateNStatus`

```
 dcast.data.table(test, betnr+year~status, length,
                       fill=NA_integer_, value.var='status')
 #     betnr year SHORT fire hire normal
#1: 50536224 1996    NA   NA    2     NA
#2: 50536224 1997    NA   NA   NA      2
#3: 50536224 1998     1    1   NA      1
#4: 50536224 1999    NA    1   NA     NA
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand why `value.var='year'`. I understand that in this scenario it does not matter, but shouldn't that be 'status', the column containing the values?

Comment: @FooBar Yes, you can use it as `status`.  Here, it is the same.